# MVC App Works in Visual Studio, but not IIS7

Tags: c#, iis-7, cassini, fips

Working on a an ASP.NET MVC Project, and I'm having some difficulties deploying to a shared dev server.

Locally, when debugging using the local Visual Studio 2008 server, everything works peachy. However, once deployed, I receive the following error:

```
    Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.## Heading ##

Parser Error Message: Unable to find an entry point named 'BCryptGetFipsAlgorithmMode' in DLL 'bcrypt.dll'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="APPLICATION_NAME.Web.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>


Source File: /APPLICATION_NAME/global.asax    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4927; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927
```

In the error log:

```
Event sequence: 1 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/APPLICATION_NAME-4-128995312096183595 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /APPLICATION_NAME 
    Application Path: E:\PROJECTS\APPLICATION\APPLICATION_NAME\APPLICATION_NAME\app\APPLICATION_NAME.Web\ 
    Machine name: PC

Process information: 
    Process ID: 4608 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Unable to find an entry point named 'BCryptGetFipsAlgorithmMode' in DLL 'bcrypt.dll'. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost/APPLICATION_NAME 
    Request path: /APPLICATION_NAME 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 6 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)


Custom event details:
```

After finding the deployment error, I tried adding an application locally, and that seems to result in the same application.

On my local dev machine, I'm using Windows 7 RTM (x64), and on the shared server I'm running Windows Server 2008 Standard (x86).

Poked around, and my FIPS encryption in Local Security Policy is disabled, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: When you say "I tried adding an application locally" does that mean you tried running it on Win7 in full IIS7 rather than just the Visual Studio webserver?

Answer (score 2):

I had some issues in the past when developing on a x64 and deploying to a x86 environment.  Under the platform target are you compiling to "Any CPU", x86 or x64?

Try compiling directly to x86 and see if that gives helps.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Bcrypt.net from [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx)? If so you need to build it with a different dll name (so for example build it as BCryptNet.dll)

The problem is that there is a new windows API in Vista/Windows 2008 that tries to load bcrypt.dll and if you have a bcrypt.dll in your web app bin/ directory it can't find the system dll.